# Monacaで作成したAndroidアプリで `com.android.vending.BILLING` の許可を削除する方法

Tags: android, monaca

Monacaで作成したAndroidアプリにおいて
アイテム課金がないものなのですが
インストールボタンの下に【アプリ内購入あり】と表記されています。

下記が該当のアプリです。
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.madeingunma.girlfriend

この件をgoogleに問い合わせたところ下記のような返答を頂きました。

> Play ストアにてアプリ内購入を表示しないように、
>   マニフェストにてcom.android.vending.BILLINGの許可を削除して下さい。

monacaの設定で可能でしょうか？
また、その他の方法がございましたらご教授頂けないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

AndroidManifest.xmlにて下記の内容がないか確認してみてください。

```
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

ファイルの場所は下記のとおりです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Monaca上でmanifestファイルにその記述はありませんが、
AppCのプラグインを組み込んだ状態で、ビルドしてできたapkをzip解凍してmanifestファイルを確認したところ、BILLINGの記述が追加されていました。

Comment: Monacaに問い合わせたところ、AppCCloud標準SDKの設定のため追加されているのではないか、とのことでした。また、現在対応予定を検討中とのことでした。